# unable to execute a C program, using MINGW

Tags: c, pointers, mingw

I am not able to execute even a simple c code through the mingW development environment. This code works fine

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char ans[5];
    printf("Enter yes or no");
    scanf("%s", ans);   
    printf("You just entered", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

But whenever I convert the datatype of ans to `char*` and then execute the .exe file that has been created by the command

```
gcc basic.c -o basic.exe
```

I am not able to see the output, it just says **basic.exe has stopped working**.
I don know if there is some issues in the installation in the mingW or what.

Comment: Provide code sample (full code, if it is about the same size) that lead to exacution fail

Comment: this is the code I am just changing `char[5] ans` to `char * ans`.

Comment: For case `char * ans;` see answer of Dr.Haimovitz below. The problem is: your pointer point to "nothing"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not suppose to see an output, the program is suppose to crash because
Its not enough to change ans to char*, you need to allocate a place for the string using malloc:

```
ans=malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
```

And also the printf should be:

```
printf("....%s"，ans);
```

Comment: ...and `printf("You just entered", ans);` doesn't do what is expected either. Where is the `%s`?

Comment: there was %s in code I just forgot to paste that here, btw its working now

Answer (score 1):

To has no problem with memory consider the following example:

```cpp
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char * ans = NULL;
    // memory allocation
    ans = (char*) malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
    if( ans == NULL) // check memory
        return 1; // end of program
    printf("Enter yes or no : ");
    // reading input with length limitation
    scanf("%4s", ans);
    // string output   
    printf("You just entered %s\n", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

If you enter more then 4 characters, 5th and others will be skipped (leaved in the input buffer).